# get_token() is not defined

Tags: c++, function, undefined, token

I'm reading "Principles and Practice Using C++" and I'm stuck on chapter 6, The book has given this example:

> How would we use Tokens in the calculator? We can read out input into
>   a vector of Tokens:

```
    #include <std_lib_facilities.h>

class Token {
public:
        char kind;
        double value;
        Token(char ch = char())
            :kind(ch), value(0){}
        Token(char ch, double val)
            :kind(ch), value(val){}
};

Token get_token(); //read a token from cin
vector<Token> tok; //we'll put the tokens here

int main()
{
    while(cin){
        Token t = get_token();
        tok.push_back(t);
    }
}
```

`get_token()` is not defined and I don't know what should be inside the function's body to define it myself, there is not mention in the book.....

Comment: We can only imagine what could that book contain in the chapter you mentioned, and what the goal of your program is.

Comment: @vsoftco I'd imagine that the goal of the program is a calculator since that's what [BigRedMachine](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4294184/bigredmachine) mentioned.

Comment: I hope that's not actually code from the book since the loop seems improperly controlled. If `get_token` encounters eof the "token" is still pushed onto the vector.

Comment: First define a token. A token in this instance would be the smallest meaningful value of an expression. Since you are building a Calculator, consider a simple expression: `10 + 2 =`. In this case, '10', '+', '2', and '=' would be considered Tokens. Consider how you would fit those tokens into your Token structure. Then work out how to parse those individual tokens using cin.

Comment: @ooga A default constructor is sometimes used as the null value. For example `std::istream_iterator`

Comment: This is just a part of the calculator program and later in the book it will add the rest of it, but this is the first step and I don't know how that function is supposed to read a token from cin ?

Comment: @JonathanMee Good point. `get_token` could return an "end-of-input" token that's added to the vector. Still, that just makes the function even more difficult for a beginner to code. @BigRedMachine Look for errata for the book online. The function may have accidentally been left out.

Comment: @fileoffset I'm a just a beginner and I really don't know how I should do that. I don't know what Bjarne was thinking when he left that function there without any explanation, and this book is supposed to be for the beginners as well !

Comment: There's an implementation here: http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/calculator00.cpp

Comment: @BigRedMachine This function is left as an exercise to the user ;)

Comment: Thanks ooga, is this book even for beginners ? the last 5 chapters were explained very well, but suddenly in chapter 6 it seems like Bjarne thinks he is only teaching to experienced programmers....

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what the book uses, so I used a char of 'n' to represent a token that contains a number (versus an operator). And a Token with a char of 'z' to indicate it is past all valid tokens. No error checking here for invalid input (not number or operator). Need to hit control-d on a blank line for this to end.

```
 //read a token from cin
Token get_token()
{
    string word;
    cin >> word;
    if ( cin.eof() )
    { 
      Token temp('z');
      return temp;
    }
    if ( word.length() == 1)
    {
        switch (word[0])
    {
        case '+':
        case '-':
        case '/':
        case '*':
        case '=':
        {
           Token temp(word[0]);
           return temp;
        }
        default:
        {
          Token temp('n',stof(word));
          return temp;
        }
    }
    }
    else 
    {
    Token temp('n',stof(word));
    return temp;
    }
}

vector<Token> tok; //we'll put the tokens here

int main()
{
    cout << "enter an expression to calculate - control-d on blank line to terminate" << endl;
    while (cin)
    {
         Token t = get_token();
         tok.push_back(t);
    }  
}
```

To eliminate the non-value token at the end:

```
Token t = get_token();
while (cin)
{
    tok.push_back(t);
    t = get_token();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check author's website for full code: http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/calculator00.cpp
`get_token()` function should be like this:

```
Token get_token()    // read a token from cin
{
    char ch;
    cin >> ch;    // note that >> skips whitespace (space, newline, tab, etc.)

    switch (ch) {
 //not yet   case ';':    // for "print"
 //not yet   case 'q':    // for "quit"
    case '(': case ')': case '+': case '-': case '*': case '/': 
        return Token(ch);        // let each character represent itself
    case '.':
    case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
    case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
        {    
            cin.putback(ch);         // put digit back into the input stream
            double val;
            cin >> val;              // read a floating-point number
            return Token('8',val);   // let '8' represent "a number"
        }
    default:
        error("Bad token");
    }
}
```